# Can transparent and hidden objects coexist in Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I would like to be able to draw a transparent object and a completely hidden object at the same time in Forge Viewer.
To do this, I tried to use the following method,
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/#isolate-node-model

It was possible to make objects in the hidden state transparent or invisible, however it was impossible to make the two states coexist.
Is there a way to have an object in two states at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's quite possible.

1. Activate Ghosting as normal (see settings).
2. Change some objects to ghosting by setting their dbid with viewer.hide(dbid)
3. Completely hide other objects using `viewer.impl.visibilityManager.setNodeOff(dbid,true)` where dbid is the object's id.

This will allow you to have fully visible objects, ghosted objects, and completely invisible objects.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to manipulate the transparency of the object as I wanted.